Using a pair of dropdown elements to augment URL inside an HTML embed on the Wix platform using Javascript messaging
Product:
Velo, iFrame, HTML embed (Wix.com, isolated from other elements), dropdown
What are you trying to achieve:
I want to display an archive of PDF files on a single page on our public library's new Wix site. I have basic embedding of the PDF viewer worked out and a license.
What I'm interested in this: my PDF Viewer is embedded in the Wix page using the html embed element, using an iframe. I have two drop-down selection boxes on this page, and they are for year and month selection, respectively. I want to message the selected year and then the selected month to the PDF viewer script to simply augment and load a different URL based on the selection. All PDFs are hosted elsewhere on a Digital Ocean droplet, just for file serving.
Is this possible? My current html embed that I want to automate with dropdown selectors is this:
    <div id="pspdfkit" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; max-width: 1920px;"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.cloud.pspdfkit.com/pspdfkit-web@2024.5.2/pspdfkit.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            if (PSPDFKit !== undefined && typeof PSPDFKit === "object") {
                PSPDFKit.load({
                    container: "#pspdfkit",
                    document: "https://domain.tld/1962_December_etc.pdf",
                    // licenseKey: "foo-bar",
                });
            } else {
                console.error("PSPDFKit library not found");
            }
        });
    </script>

How feasible is this, using two dropdowns? I'm not familiar with JavaScript coding, though I can vaguely follow along and work things out slowly. (I am generally a good learner and have some experience using Python successfully with some help from StackOverflow to fill in the gaps in my understanding.)
We have about twenty years of newspaper issues (they've been combined by month), so this sort of solution is key to surfacing them without creating a million Wix pages.
What have you already tried:
My question hinges on the ability of Wix to allow Javascript messaging between otherwise isolated HTML embeds and their Velo framework. Since this is mostly really a Javascript question, I was hoping for some explanation to help work through the problem and illustrate a solution so that I can not just implement this bit of functionality but learn from the issue and grow my ability to mentally parse these sorts of problems. Link to the Velo documentation: (Working with the HTML iFrame element with Velo.) (https://dev.wix.com/docs/develop-websites/articles/wix-editor-elements/other-elements/html-i-frame-element/working-with-the-html-iframe-element#velo-working-with-the-html-iframe-element)
Are my assumptions correct about being able to use a pair of drop-down elements to augment the URL otherwise hardcoded into the HTML embed using Javascript messaging?
Additional information:
This project is to surface historical records to the public via the new website for a public library, particularly old local newspapers. Your help is invaluable and much appreciated.


You’ve got dropdowns for picking the year and month.

The script will change the PDF based on what you select.

Just make sure your URL matches the files you have.
<select id="yearDropdown">
<option value="2023">2023</option>
<option value="2022">2022</option>
</select>

<select id="monthDropdown">
<option value="January">January</option>
<option value="February">February</option>
</select>



and javascript
    <script>
    let currentDocumentUrl = "https://domain.tld/2023_January.pdf"; // Default PDF

    function loadPdf(url) {
        PSPDFKit.load({
            container: "#pspdfkit",
            document: url,
        });
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        loadPdf(currentDocumentUrl); // Load the default PDF

        const yearDropdown = document.getElementById("yearDropdown");
        const monthDropdown = document.getElementById("monthDropdown");

        function updatePdf() {
            const year = yearDropdown.value;
            const month = monthDropdown.value;
            currentDocumentUrl = `https://domain.tld/${year}_${month}.pdf`; // Construct new URL
            loadPdf(currentDocumentUrl); // Load the new PDF
        }

        yearDropdown.addEventListener("change", updatePdf); // Update on year change
        monthDropdown.addEventListener("change", updatePdf); // Update on month change
    });
</script>


Hello. Thank you so much for helping. I can follow along pretty well with what your code is doing even though I'm new to Javascript. Unfortunately, while the viewer loads in the code I came up with, the selection drop-downs don't update the URL and reload the viewer. I must be missing something.
